# Database script for Joomla upgrade from 1.7 to 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

I am looking for the script that does the database changes and upgrades the Joomla installation from Joomla 1.7 to Joomla 2.5. Thus I am not looking for changes in the code as I can check those from SVN. Having access to this script can allow me to just run these scripts on the server where I cannot run the automatic upgrade from Joomla admin.

Update: As @Elin indicated. Snapshot of the sql folder under com_admin. Which sql queries are executed from here?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the sql folder of com_admin.

Comment: Thanks,I suppose this is what I am looking for although the sql folder has updates->mysql->then a bunch of 1.7 named sql files which have very minimal sql queries. Unsure which one to use from this. I am adding the snapshot to the question description

Comment: This link here solved my earlier question. and explains everything else. Thanks @Elin for pointing in the right direction. I am going to add this link to the answer. http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/joomla/upgrade/17-to-25/manual